# C# regex extracting tags

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Say I have a few string like

```
Hi my name is <Name>
Hi <name>, shall we go for a <Drink>
```

Is it possible to get the tags captured through c# Regex? like `<Name>, <drink>` etc?
I am not able to get it right..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
Regex.Matches(myString, "<([^>]+)>");
```

PowerShell Example:

```
PS> $s = @'
>> Hi my name is <Name>
>> Hi <name>, shall we go for a <Drink>
>> '@
>>
PS> [regex]::Matches($s,  '<([^>]+)>') | ft

Groups                Success Captures      Index      Length Value
------                ------- --------      -----      ------ -----
{<Name>, Name}           True {<Name>}         14           6 <Name>
{<name>, name}           True {<name>}         25           6 <name>
{<Drink>, Drink}         True {<Drink>}        51           7 <Drink>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"</?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>"
```

To use it, try something like this:

```
try
{
    Regex regexObj = new Regex("</?[a-z][a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Match matchResults = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
    while (matchResults.Success)
    {
        // Do Stuff

        // matched text: matchResults.Value
        // match start: matchResults.Index
        // match length: matchResults.Length
        matchResults = matchResults.NextMatch();
    } 
}
catch (ArgumentException ex)
{
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something even simpler like using C#s String.Replace?  You pass in the string  to be replaced and give it whatever value you want to replace it with.

See here for examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx

Comment: thanks for your response.
I cannot do it the way you suggensted, because the values are in a DB